# Is there any command tool available to extract frame from video/stream and writes out timestamp of each frame?

Tags: linux, command-line, video, video-streaming

Since ffmpeg doesn't support command line argument to writes out current frame timestamp as output file name, I am desperately looking for a command line tool that support that extract image from video/video-stream and output current frame timestamp as file name.

Is there any tool available for such requirement?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: This is not a software shopping question. Since there is no option available so I have to ask such question to find my own way.

Comment: "I am desperately looking for a command line tool" == "question seeking product."

Comment: "I have to ask such question to find my own way" Then ask in the right place, which is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a multi-step process, using ffmpeg and a batch renaming tool such as [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/).

Suppose you wanted to extract every 40th frame

**#1** Extract frames and list of presentation timestamps.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select=not(mod(n\,40)) frames-%d.jpg
       -vf select=not(mod(n\,40)) -f mkvtimestamp_v2 pts.txt
```

Besides the images, you also get pts.txt which looks like this:

```
# timecode format v2
0
1600
3200
4800
6400
8000
9600
11200
12800
14400
16000
```

Those are the timestamps for the extracted frames, expressed in milliseconds

**#2** Then use a batch renaming app which supports renaming using a list to modify the filenames of the frames. Or a shell script.

Comment: I am extracting images for online (streaming) purposes. which means I can't use batching at all. Do you have any suggestion for that?